# Stop elements from shifting when resizing window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've built a header bar for my page. It consists of the  element and inside are some  elements, , . I can lay everything out nicely but when I resize the browser window everything starts to move and overlap in the header. Giving the header, or even the body a fixed with like "width: 1000px" solves this, but that is screen-size dependent.

How can I have my page such that any resizing of the browser window causes scroll bars to appear to view the hidden content, and where this would NOT be dependent on a hard-wired resolution in pixels.

Comment: Use responsive design patterns like `twitter-bootstrap` check out this http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 6):

Give your main div (often your wrap div) a `min-width: ...px`.

Like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>

.wrap {
     width: 95%;
     min-width: 900px;
}
```

In the example above, the wrapper div will always be at least 900px.
When the window gets resized to a smaller width, the scrollbars will appear.

If the screen is bigger than 900px, the div will have a 95% width.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. On a related issue, should I wrap the header in a div, or is it ok to use those styles directly on the header?

Comment: Yes, you could use this on your header too. With the side note that it depends on how your website structure is built. It may be better to wrap it all in a wrapper div.

Comment: If it works out for you, please don't forget to mark the answer as solution.

Comment: I tried this. I saw the scrollbars sometimes but things are still moving on the page.